# When does an iOS program run `Run Script` and load Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode

Before I run my App, I would like to run a external shell to update my Info.plist.

With Build Phases->Run Script, I can run my external shell. And here is my question, I saw Info.plist update the data when the program was building, but when I ran into my app, I found that the data read from plist was the former old data.

I also found another funny thing.

One side, if I just built the project(command + B), I saw plist update and then I ran the program, the data showed in UI was new data.

Another side,if I used the Run Button in Xcode, I saw the Info.plist update when Xcode show build successed, however, the data showed in UI was old data.

So, what happens? Could you help me to solve it to let my data be always the newest.

=============

Now, I have moved my 'Run Script' to run external shell before 'Compile Source(swift files)', and it works. However, I still can't understand, since it runs during build time, why the running program can't get the right data from Info.plist if I runs my 'Run Script' after 'Compile Source(swift files)'? does the program load in the data during its run time or compile time?

Comment: The "Build Phases->Run Script" is only build time thing

Comment: where is the script in the build phases? does it need to be a script? can you do it as part of the build settings?

Comment: @sage444 yes, it is the run time thing. But the question is since my shell has been called during build time. Why the program use old data when it runs?

Comment: here is my 'Run Script' code `COMMITHASHCODE="${SRCROOT}/ExternalScript/commitHashCode.sh"
if [ -x "$COMMITHASHCODE" ]; then
exec "$COMMITHASHCODE"
fi`

Answer (score 0):

Building an app involves many different phases. Compiling sources is just one of them, there's also linking, copying resources, signing, etc. Some of them are explicitly listed in the "Build Phases" tab, others are not.

So it's really a matter of running the script at the appropriate time in the build process so that the Info.plist is modified before it is actually used by the build process.

If you click on the "Report Navigator" icon (last icon in the list at the top of the left-side panel), then on the last build, you'll see the report of that build which lists all the steps that were performed during the build process, including running scripts and processing the Info.plist.